# How to have up-to-date variables after the execution of a thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, attributes, touch-event

I'm using `Bluetooth` in my Android application, so in `onTouchEvent()`, I run `startDiscovery()`. Then, in `onReceive()`, I change the value of some attributes. Back in `onTouchEvent()`, I use a `System.sleep(8000)` to wait before printing the values I just get. 
I can see that the values are well modified, but there is "one call of gap". I mean that it's the values of the previous call to `onTouchEvent()` which are printed.

Do you know how to get the actual values of the last call? Thank you.

The function which is called when a bluetooth device is found :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            amp = 0;
            name = null;

            if (device.getAddress().equals("00:11:22:33:44")) {
                amp = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
                name = device.getName();
            }
        }
    }
```

In onTouchEvent() :

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            SystemClock.sleep(8000);

            print_RSSI(x, y);
```

The function which is called to print after that :

```
private void print_RSSI(float x, float y) {

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Rel1);
        TextView tv;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(name + ":" + String.valueOf(amp));
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 40);
        params.leftMargin = (int) x;
        params.topMargin = (int) y;
        rl.addView(tv, params);
    }
```